# Content DB restore problem (SP2007)

Tags: 2007, restore, content-database

I'm having an issue restoring a content database and hopefully one of you guys can help me out.

I'm trying to replicate a live issue environment in a new temporary dev environment for troubleshooting purposes. To do this I have built a new SP2007 farm and patched it to the same level as the prod farm. I've got a copy of the MDF and LDF of the live content DB and have attached it to my Dev SQL server.

I've created a new web application in dev and pointed it to the newly attached DB on the dev sql server. This kind of works as I get 1 site collection listed and it even has the correct title. The trouble is when I browse to the site I get a 404 not found. If I manually navigate to the view all site content page (.../_layouts/viewlsts.aspx) I can see the page but there is no content showing. No lists, no document libraries, nothing. It's like the content db has only partially restored. I should also add that if I run some queries over the content db there is loads of content in it - lists, libraries, sites - about 500GB!

I've tried iisresets and I've gone round in circles attaching/detaching the content DBs but I'm still just seeing this empty shell of a site.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? I've done the usual googling but can't find anyone else with the same problem :(

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is it root level site collection? what you will see in the central admin > view all site collections? also check the size of site collection from central admin > configure quota & locks...

Comment: Yes it's a root level site collection. The size of the site is being reported as 0MB. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just backup the live database and restore it to the temporary server using stsadm?